# What would be the complement of the title "Goals Achieved"?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

What would be a title that is complementary to the title "Goals Achieved"?

By "complementary", I mean a title that can be used in contrast to "Goals Achieved" to refer to the goals that now need to be achieved following the goals achieved.

I thought of something along the lines of "Goals Expected". However, this makes it sound as if these goals are sure to be achieved, which is not necessarily true.

I'm looking for a succinct title.

Comment: *Complement* is vague.  Are you asking about words to add to the partial title  “Goals Achieved”, or words to replace that title, or a new title for another section, or content of the paragraphs after the title, or something else? (Please respond by editing and improving question)

Comment: Anticipated Outcomes? Future Benchmarks? It really kind of depends on what the situation is...

Comment: "Goals yet to achieve"?

Comment: Normally one would just write "Goals".

Comment: *Succint* is a common misspelling of succinct.  *Succinct* has a total of 3 c's in it.

Comment: If you're not hedging, _goals missed_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest *Goals Remaining* as this reinforces an expectation that they will (should, must) be achieved in time.

Answer (score 0):

Upcoming Goals would likely suit your needs.

Alternatively, Impending, future, and new could also work.